# ExtJS TreeGrid - Context Menu anchors incorrectly

Tags: extjs

I have an ExtJS TreeGrid which I'm attempting to add a ContextMenu onto when a user right clicks. The right click is working fine, but there's one little niggle; the menu doesn't show in the exact position where the user right clicks. Rather, it anchors to the beginning of the node - so if a user right clicks half way across the node they need to travel across the screen to click on a menu item - quite annoying.

This seems a little odd as I have this exact feature working perfectly for the ExtJS Tree. Perhaps it's an ExtJS TreeGrid bug?

**Why isn't the contextMenu showing exactly where the user right-clicks in the Tree Grid?**

Here's the listener:

```
                  listeners: {
                        contextmenu: function(node,event){
                            node.select();
                            myContextMenu.show(node.ui.getAnchor());
                        }
                  }
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

On further inspection, the same thing is happening within the ExtJS Tree - perhaps this can't be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question, but this sorts it:

```
                   listeners: {
                        contextmenu: function(node,event){
                            node.select();
                            myContextMenu.showAt(event.xy);
                        }
                    }
```